# DAX spread quantity over 5 days

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with columns Date, Type, and Qty.

Every time I see the type 'Start', I want to spread that quantity over the next 5 days (including the Start day). Note, the Start day may not always be the 6th day as in the example.

[image]

Comment: Are the dates always continuous or could there be a gap i.e. no row representing one of the five days to spread the values over?

Comment: @BarneyL The dates are always continuous.

Comment: Is there only ever one row per day?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for three measures something like this (syntax may be a little off as I'm writing without a platform to test on).

The first adds the normal records only.

```
SumNormal := CALCULATE(SUM(Qty),mytable[Type] = "Normal"
```

The second looks for the starts in the last 5 days and then divides by five.

```
SumStart := 
  VAR CurrentDate = mytable[Date]
  VAR StartDate = DATEADD([CurrentDate],-4,day)
CALCULATE(SUM(Qty)
   ,mytable[Type] = "Normal"
   ,FILTER(mytable,[Date]>= StartDate && [Date] <= CurrentDate)
)/5
```

Finally Add the two:

```
SumQty := [SumNormal] + [SumStart]
```

The above covers the basics but is relatively simple, it will only really work running at day level. Handling a total where some but not all of the five days the start value is spread over gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: If you're able to though it would be better to split the Start rows into five day by day rows either while outputting them from your source system or in power query while loading the data in. That warrants a whole new question and approach though.